# Amazon's Alexa & Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, electricity, grama, pesik-reisha

Does anyone know of a definitive credible source about voice activated devices on Shabbat?

Alexa has made life so much easier as my elderly mother can just use her voice to contact us.  We have made it so each room in her home is covered by an Alexa device because of this.  It necessitates at least one of us carrying a cell phone, but we do not have to answer the phone on Shabbat as the ringtone alone tells us it is mum.

Does anyone know of a credible source that discusses voice activated devices and Alexa in particular?  I am not concerned about Alexa being used to turn on an oven or other device.   The only device that responds to Alexa in her home is the locks on her front door.

What I am concerned with is that the device is constantly listening.   Does this mean on Shabbat that those of us that do not need her for medical reasons need to be silent in their home on Shabbos?

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10892/voice-activated-electronics-on-shabbat

Comment: Alexa only activates when you say "Alexa" (or one of the aliases). So as long as you don't say that, it should be fine.

Comment: @Daniel What part of Alexa only activates upon saying Alexa? Why shouldn't there be a problem with the "Activation circuits"? Why is it not a Psik Reisha?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82711/air-purifier-with-led-sensor-on-shabbat/82737#82737

Comment: According to R Aurbach that electricity is a derabanan, in this case it would be a pesik reishei delo nicha (since he doesnt care about alexa listening) and would be permitted. I think nowadays we all must rely on such pesakim since we live in world filled with electronic sensors (eyes), refrigerators etc.. and its not possible to move (or should i say live) without activating them in some way!

Comment: Hey there, WestonKohn! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. You should probably consult a rabbi about this.